# Separar un string cada X cantidad de dígitos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Partiendo de una variable que contiene un string:

```
var a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" //Contiene 20 "a"
```

Deseo obtener una nueva variable, que contenga el mismo string separado cada 4 dígitos. Es decir, obtener lo siguiente.

```
var a = "aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa" //Contiene 20 "a"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, usando  `reduce()`:

```js
var a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

var res = [...a].reduce((p, c, i) => p += (i && !(i % 4)) ? "-" + c : c, "");

console.log(res);
```

Lo que hacemos es evaluar si la posición es múltiplo de 4, si es así le agregamos un guión adelante, sino no. Evaluamos también que no sea 0, porque sino le agrega un guión al principio.

Otro enfoque es usando `.replace()`:

```js
var a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

var res = a.replace(/(a{4})(\B)/g,"$1-");

console.log(res);
```

La idea de la regex es buscar grupos de 4 a's pero no seguido de limite de palabra (\B). En cada coincidencia le agregamos un `-`

Otra enfoque distinto sería construir el string de cero:

```js
var a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

const grupos = 5;

var res = Array(a.length/grupos).fill(Array(grupos).fill(a[0]).join("")).join("-");

console.log(res);
```

Va a funcionar mientras length y grupos sean múltiplos.

Answer (score 2):

En generar evito trabajar con expresiones regulares a no ser que se trate de un caso en concreto, es buena solución pero me parece esta más adaptable:

```
var a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
const separate = 4; 
a = a.split('').map( (x,i)=> (i>0 && i%separate==0)? "-"+x : x ).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es otra forma de hacerlo:

```js
let a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
let transform = [];

for(let i = 0;i < a.length; i += 4){
  transform.push(a.substr(i, 4));
}

console.log(transform.join('-'));
```

De todas formas la del colega @Emeeus me parece la mas acertada/simple

Answer (score 0):

Buscando por Internet, encontré este código, espero sea de ayuda, las últimas líneas las agregué para eliminar el último guión.

```js
var str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
var len = 4;
var regex = new RegExp(".{"+len+"}", "g");
var trail = str.length - (str.length % len);

var parts = str.match(regex);
parts.push(str.substring(trail));

let newString = parts.join('-');

let newString2 = newString.substr(0,(newString.length-1));

console.log(newString2);
```